# vagrant doesn't find installed libvirt plugin (host Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, libvirt, vagrant

I can't get vagrant working with libvirt.

I first used the distro packages, but it produced the same error you see in my description below.
Then I removed every distro vagrant package and installed the packages provided by hashicorp:

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

then I installed the libvirt-vagrant plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching formatador-0.3.0.gem
Fetching fog-core-2.2.4.gem
Fetching fog-json-1.2.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-linux.gem
Fetching fog-xml-0.1.4.gem
Fetching ruby-libvirt-0.8.0.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Fetching fog-libvirt-0.9.0.gem
Fetching vagrant-libvirt-0.7.0.gem
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-libvirt (0.7.0)'!
```

However the `vagrant up --provider=libvirt` still fails:

```
The provider 'libvirt' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'debian11'. Please use a provider that exists.

Vagrant knows about the following providers: virtualbox, hyperv, docker
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this process on a fresh VM but these are the steps I followed(In my testing I felt libvirt storage is very slow, is it due to my hardware or it is expected ?)

The Steps I followed

```bsh
 curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
 sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vagrant

 apt install vagrant-libvirt
 apt-get build-dep vagrant ruby-libvirt
 apt-get install qemu libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients ebtables dnsmasq-base
 apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libvirt-dev zlib1g-dev ruby-dev
 apt-get install libguestfs-tools
 vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
 
 vagrant init fedora/32-cloud-base
 vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

Well I am doing this all in a cloud VM, while doing up I got errors like `Error while creating domain: Error saving the server: Call to virDomainDefineXML failed: End of file while reading data: Input/output error` I hope it's no relevant to your query.

Hope it helps.

Refernce:

- https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads
- https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt

Comment: Cloud VM's don't always support "nested virtualization" (Running a VM in a VM). (because the Cloud VMs are VMs, they can't always run VMs. Many cloud providers offer bare metal Infrastructure as a Service for doing VM things)